# Inspect element tab open in excel add ins using react js

Tags: office-addins, vscode-debugger, excel-web-addins, ms-office-addin

I am using  React to build an Excel task pane add-in it use for browser interaction with excel sheet but if i have problem occur then i can't figure out because of no console tab is present for this add in so can anyone tell me how can i use inspect element in excel react to build an excel task pane add-in

i use different method like edge legacy development tools etc but it didn't work This  are the link i use to solve this error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-overview
please help me

Comment: Do you have related screenshots to clarify this issue?